# Comparação de desempenho em Android: Canvas vs OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl

Existe alguma tabela comparativa de desempenho, ou alguma listagem com regras/diretrizes, que me indique a partir de qual momento compensa utilizar OpenGL ES no Android, em vez do par Canvas + Activity configurada como `hardwareAccelerated="true"`, para fazer desenhos constantes, como por exemplo, em um jogo?

Ou é sempre mais vantajoso utilizar OpenGL ES nesse cenário?

Comment: Se você está renderizando via `hardwareAccelerated="true"` então está usando o OpenGL por de baixo dos panos, mas através de uma API mais "fácil". Usar o OpenGL diretamente sempre vai ser mais rápido. Para saber se a diferença é significante para a sua aplicação especifica, só testando mesmo...

Comment: Sim, concordo. Mas tenho testado vários jogos de terceiros, e por incrível que pareça, alguns poucos deles funcionam mais lentamente em um Galaxy S4, do que em um Galaxy Y, o que, a princípio, não deveria ocorrer. Não tenho acesso ao código fonte deles, mas comecei a supor que deva ter algum tipo de relação entre utilizar OpenGL ES diretamente, e utilizar um Canvas acelerado "por debaixo do pano".

Answer (score 2):

exatamente como o comentário do Guilherme propôs: o OpenGL tem um acesso de mais baixo nível que o Canvas e será mais rápido.

No caso da lentidão em alguns dispositivos pode ter muitos motivos que variam desde a má programação utilizando o OpenGL (diversas chamadas desnecessárias no render por exemplo) ou o tratamento do render pelo driver do fabricante (alguns colocam implementações em situações específicas que tornam o render mais rápido).